# PowerShell: How to place "Write-Host" inside SQL code before "ROLLBACK TRANSACTION"

Tags: sql, powershell

In below power-shell script, I'm executing multiple SQL statement. All SQL statements are in TRANSACTION. Now In case any error, the execution falls under BEGIN CATCH and all my transaction are ROLLBACK.

Now here I would like to add a message using  "Write-Host" before or after `ROLLBACK TRANSACTION`.

```
[CmdletBinding()]
Param(
[string]$SQLServer='(local)'
)
# Database Update
Write-Host "Update Database" -ForegroundColor Green
& sqlcmd.exe -S $SQLServer -Q @"
USE [Test]
BEGIN TRANSACTION
BEGIN TRY
INSERT INTO DBO.A1 (Name) VALUES ('test1')
INSERT INTO DBO.A2 (Name) VALUES ('test1')
COMMIT TRANSACTION
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
SELECT ERROR_MESSAGE() as ErrorMessage;

ROLLBACK TRANSACTION

END CATCH
"@
```

Is this possible?

Comment: The query text is passed, as a whole, to SQL Server as a block of text to be compiled and executed. SQL Server has *no* knowledge, at that point, that the connection was initiated as part of a powershell script.

Comment: If you use the `SqlServer` module and `Invoke-Sqlcmd`, you can simply catch the error produced by the statement instead of having to rely on the output of `sqlcmd`. (`TRY .. CATCH` should become unnecessary if you use `SET XACT_ABORT ON`, but if you want to retain it, use `THROW` in the `CATCH`.)

Comment: any example code please?

Comment: [The docs have examples](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sqlserver/invoke-sqlcmd?view=sqlserver-ps#examples).

Answer (score 0):

```
@"
USE [Test]
BEGIN TRANSACTION
BEGIN TRY
INSERT INTO DBO.A1 (Name) VALUES ('test1')
INSERT INTO DBO.A2 (Name) VALUES ('test1')
COMMIT TRANSACTION
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
SELECT ERROR_MESSAGE() as ErrorMessage;

ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
$(Write-Host 'blah')

END CATCH
"@
```

Comment: Thanks, `blah` is coming at top and not after  `SELECT ERROR_MESSAGE() as ErrorMessage;`

Comment: Question, can I return a variable right after `ROLLBACK TRANSACTION`?

Comment: ouch, my bad, sorry. im just occasionally playing with this sort of stuff. btw, sqlcmd.exe may or may not be the best option. how about System.Data.SqlClient ?

Comment: anything is fine. but may be I can return a variable for TRY/CATCH and use this variable later in script

Answer (score 0):

I tried like that,

```js
BEGIN CATCH
    SELECT ERROR_MESSAGE() as ErrorMessage;
 
 ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
 
 $($Result =1)
 
END CATCH
"@

if($Result =1)
{
 Write-Host "Update Database FAIL" -ForegroundColor Green
}
```